# Custom language not added properly in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 for my project. However, I wanted to add my own language for validation, so I used [laravel-lang](https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang) and placed the `fa` folder inside the `resources/lang/` directory.

Then I added these to `config/app.php`:

```
'locale' => 'fa',
'fallback_locale' => 'fa',
'faker_locale' => 'fa_IR',
```

And I also re-run the `php artisan serve` to test if it works or not, but the problem is, it does not work and still shows the English messages for Login/Register Controller validation.

So what is going wrong here? How can I add my language properly?

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan cache:clear` command?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use **translation** you should use proper syntax to translate your variables or your sentences:

`{{ _('your_variable') }}`

If you use this syntax and the problem exist yet, check your html **language meta tag** or **lang** attribute:

It should be `<html lang="fa">`.